# Tengo un problema con Angular al crear proyecto

Tags: angular, ng

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo Angular y al crear un proyecto no pasa de ahí, tal y como en la imagen.

[image: Angular]

O sea, no me pasa al siguiente procedimiento de crear los paquetes. Como en esta imagen en donde hice el procedimiento de crear un proyecto, pero en otro equipo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Versión de Angular:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos!

Comment: Te sugiero editar la pregunta para que la comunidad puda responder mas rapido lee como elaborar una pregunta aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hola. 
Soy nuevo en la plataforma, y gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Que tal, con respecto a angular debes tener instalado node js, typescript y angular, crea un directorio abrelo desde el cmd posicionandote en el  y puedes crear un componente con ng  new app lo del routing , css etc pues es para recargarlos o los puedes implementar despues.

Comment: Checa tu conexión a internet, prueba con Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Carlos en el primer paso de la instalación angular te esta consultando si vas a usar su módulo de angular-routing o no. Si pones que SI, te va a crear el módulo appRoutingModule y lo va a agregar en tu app.module.ts dentro del array de imports de tu @NgModule al momento de crear el proyecto.

Si pones que NO, entonces no agregará este módulo pero lo podes agregar después usando el comando:

```
ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app
```

recuerda importar este modulo y agregarlo en tu app.module.ts.

Luego en el siguiente paso angular te consulta si deseas utilizar alguna plantilla de estilos. Solo debes seleccionar CSS puro o si utilizas algún pre-procesador de estilos como SASS o LESS selecciona el que uses. De esta forma angular sabe que tipo de plantilla de estilo debe crear cuando utilices comandos de CLI para generar los componentes.

Luego de eso le das enter y debería finalizar la instalación. Con el comando:

```
ng version
```

verificas que te aparezca tu versión de angular.

Comment: Hola Nicolás, gracias por colaborar, te sugiero que antes de responder, leas atentamente la pregunta, para generar respuestas acordes, en este caso, el OP manifiesta que el sistema se queda colgado, haciendo la operación que le indicas... por lo que tu respuesta no estaría solucionando el problema.